# How to replace &nbsp with white space

Tags: python, django

I'm using this to remove

```
{{i.content|truncatewords:30|striptags|safe|cut:"&nbsp;"}}
```

but it leaves no spaces between words.

I want to replace each `&nbsp;` with a white space.

Comment: Maybe do the opposite of this [custom nbsp filter](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2842/).  (Of course I'm not sure why that code is implemented with split/join rather than `replace()`.)

Comment: Hi, maybe I didn't understand very well but do u want replace it in a string? if so you can easily do with replace()

Answer (score 2):

Use a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='nbsp2space', is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def nbsp2space(value):
    return re.sub('&nbsp;', ' ', value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Use it like

```
{{i.content|truncatewords:30|striptags|safe|nbsp2space}}
```

Notes: `@register.filter(name='nbsp2space')` registers the filter using the provided name.  If no name is provided the actual name of the function is used. 
 `is_safe=True` says we aren't introducing unsafe characters into the value.  `@stringfilter` ensures the argument is always a string.  `re.sub()` was used over `str.replace()` because `&nbsp;` could be upper or lower case and `re.IGNORECASE` takes care of that.